# Change Toolbar color in Appcompat 21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I am testing out the new Appcompat 21 Material Design features. Therefore I've created a Toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_my_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
```

and included it in my main layout file.

Then I've set it as supportActionBar like that:

```
Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
```

It's working, but somehow I can't quite figure out how to customize the toolbar. It's grey and the text on it is black. How should I change background and text color?

I've gone through this instructions:

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

What have I overseen to change colors?

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT**:

I was able to change the background color by adding these lines of code to the theme:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/actionbar_dark</item>
```

But they won't affect the text color. What am I missing? Instead of the black text and black menu button, I'd rather prefer a white text and white menu buttons:

[image]

Comment: what does your theme look like for the activity? did you set your color for the Toolbar in there like you should?

Comment: @tyczj I am adding the theme to my post

Comment: ok well there is you answer you dont set your colors

Comment: @tyczj , Yeah, I've again edited my post, i added primarycolor and primarydarkcolor, but which attribute changes the text color?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

again this is all in the link you supplied

to change the text to white all you have to do is change the theme.

use this theme

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_my_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the same thing, it suddenly was confusing that dark actionbar had light text and light actionbar dark text... Thanks!

Comment: I have done like this, but still got the black color font, did I missing something?

Comment: So, it seems like the **@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar** on the app:theme changes the text of the toolbar to **white** and @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light changes it to black. The background color is picked from android:background attribute. Whereas on the app:popupTheme: @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark gives white text and black background and @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light gives black text and white background. https://gist.github.com/mnemonicflow/7cba09f6461ec86b22b7

Comment: Did you need to set textColorPrimary to white or not?

Comment: Thanks! :D google really messed up with the styling of the Toolbar on android. The fact that this question has 50 upvotes and 22 starts is proof of that.

Comment: If the title still stays black after setting styles. Make sure you extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: I'm Android beginner and don't want to know more about troublesome theme thingie and this code just saved my day...

Comment: This doesn't work if set custom color, not colorPrimary

Answer (score 66):

**UPDATE 12/11/2019: Material Components Library**

With the Material Components and Androidx libraries you can use:

- the **`android:background`** attribute in the layout:

  ```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  ```
- apply the default style: **`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"`** or customize the style inheriting from it:

  ```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
  ```
- override the default color using the **`android:theme`** attribute:

  ```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
  ```

with:

```
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">....</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/.....
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

**OLD: Support libraries:**
You can use a `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` theme as suggested in other answers, but you can also use a solution like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"/>
```

And you can have the full control of your ui elements with these styles:

```
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
</style>

<style name="HeaderBar">
    <item name="android:background">?colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Popup menu is still black background with white text

Comment: Not Helpful. It requires Min API level of 21

Comment: @VaibhavGupta Appcompat requires minSdk=7 not 21.

Answer (score 11):

Hey if you want to apply Material theme for only android 5.0 then you can add this theme in 
it

```
<style name="AppHomeTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">

        <!-- customize the color palette -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/blue_dark_bg</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_status_bar</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/blue_color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
```

Here below line is responsibly for text color of Actionbar of Material design.

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set a custom **toolbar** item color dynamically by creating a custom toolbar class:

```
package view;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter;
import android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView;
import android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomToolbar extends Toolbar{

    public CustomToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        ctxt = context;
    }

    int itemColor;
    Context ctxt;

    @Override 
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        Log.d("LL", "onLayout");
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        colorizeToolbar(this, itemColor, (Activity) ctxt);
    } 

    public void setItemColor(int color){
        itemColor = color;
        colorizeToolbar(this, itemColor, (Activity) ctxt);
    }



    /**
     * Use this method to colorize toolbar icons to the desired target color
     * @param toolbarView toolbar view being colored
     * @param toolbarIconsColor the target color of toolbar icons
     * @param activity reference to activity needed to register observers
     */
    public static void colorizeToolbar(Toolbar toolbarView, int toolbarIconsColor, Activity activity) {
        final PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter
                = new PorterDuffColorFilter(toolbarIconsColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        for(int i = 0; i < toolbarView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View v = toolbarView.getChildAt(i);

            doColorizing(v, colorFilter, toolbarIconsColor);
        }

      //Step 3: Changing the color of title and subtitle.
        toolbarView.setTitleTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        toolbarView.setSubtitleTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
    }

    public static void doColorizing(View v, final ColorFilter colorFilter, int toolbarIconsColor){
        if(v instanceof ImageButton) {
            ((ImageButton)v).getDrawable().setAlpha(255);
            ((ImageButton)v).getDrawable().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        }

        if(v instanceof ImageView) {
            ((ImageView)v).getDrawable().setAlpha(255);
            ((ImageView)v).getDrawable().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        }

        if(v instanceof AutoCompleteTextView) {
            ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).setTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        }

        if(v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        }

        if(v instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText)v).setTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        }

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup){
            for (int lli =0; lli< ((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); lli ++){
                doColorizing(((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(lli), colorFilter, toolbarIconsColor);
            }
        }

        if(v instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            for(int j = 0; j < ((ActionMenuView)v).getChildCount(); j++) {

                //Step 2: Changing the color of any ActionMenuViews - icons that
                //are not back button, nor text, nor overflow menu icon.
                final View innerView = ((ActionMenuView)v).getChildAt(j);

                if(innerView instanceof ActionMenuItemView) {
                    int drawablesCount = ((ActionMenuItemView)innerView).getCompoundDrawables().length;
                    for(int k = 0; k < drawablesCount; k++) {
                        if(((ActionMenuItemView)innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[k] != null) {
                            final int finalK = k;

                            //Important to set the color filter in seperate thread, 
                            //by adding it to the message queue
                            //Won't work otherwise. 
                            //Works fine for my case but needs more testing

                            ((ActionMenuItemView) innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[finalK].setColorFilter(colorFilter);

//                              innerView.post(new Runnable() {
//                                  @Override
//                                  public void run() {
//                                      ((ActionMenuItemView) innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[finalK].setColorFilter(colorFilter);
//                                  }
//                              });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

then refer to it in your layout file. Now you can set a custom color using

```
toolbar.setItemColor(Color.Red);
```

**Sources:**

I found the information to do this here: [How to dynamicaly change Android Toolbar icons color](https://snowdog.co/blog/how-to-dynamicaly-change-android-toolbar-icons-color/)

and then I edited it, improved upon it, and posted it here: [GitHub:AndroidDynamicToolbarItemColor](https://github.com/powerpoint45/AndroidDynamicToolbarItemColor)

Answer (score 5):

This is what is known as a DarkActionBar which means you should use the following theme to obtain your desired style:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/triple_height_toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of the text in the toolbar with these:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Achieve this by using the `toolbar` like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/base_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your styles.xml:

colorPrimary will be the toolbar color.

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_pressed</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Did you build this in Eclipse by the way?

Answer (score 1):

i solved this issue after more Study...

for Api21 and more use

```
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

for Lower versions use

```
   <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of your toolbar all throughout your app, leverage the styles.xml. In general, I avoid altering ui components in my java code unless I am trying to do something programatically. If this is a one time set, then you should be doing it in xml to make your code cleaner. Here is what your styles.xml will look like:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="YourAppName.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Color Primary will be your toolbar color -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Color Primary Dark will be your default status bar color -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Make sure you use the above style in your AndroidManifext.xml as such:

```
    <application
        android:theme="@style/YourAppName.AppTheme">
    </application>
```

I wanted different toolbar colors for different activities. So I leveraged styles again like this:

```
    <style name="YourAppName.AppTheme.Activity1">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/activity1_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/activity1_primaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="YourAppName.AppTheme.Activity2">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/activity2_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/activity2_primaryDark</item>
</style>
```

again, apply the styles to each activity in your AndroidManifest.xml as such:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity2"
    android:theme="@style/YourAppName.AppTheme.Activity2"
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".Activity1"
    android:theme="@style/YourAppName.AppTheme.Activity1"
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who are using AppCompatActivity with Toolbar as white background. Do use this code.

**Updated: December, 2017**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:title="Edit Your Profile"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: What is the difference with a default Toolbar?