# Android: How to Center title in ToolBar

Tags: android, toolbar

I am using ToolBar in my project first time, so i do not know how to customized the toolbar in android. I need to centered title in to the tool bar and how to do that please tell me.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android toolbar center title and custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font)

Answer (score 40):

The problem with simply adding a TextView in the Toolbar aligned center is adding menu items in the toolbar which will offset the centered text.

To get around this, I've layered the text on top of the Toolbar, not inside it. This way it doesn't matter how many icons you add, it will not offset the centered text:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This way there is no need for any extra logic to compensate for the offset spacing of back buttons/overflow menu/search icons etc. on the toolbar, because the centered text is above it, not in it.

Comment: This was useful, thanks for the idea.  I implemented it without the extra AppBarLayout layer.

Comment: But if you put it out of toolbar you can not use toolbar animation or appbar behaviour on it.

Answer (score 35):

Remember that `Toolbar` is just a `ViewGroup` like the others. So you can stuff `View`s into it. In your case, you need a `TextView` inside a `Toolbar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Some Fancy Title"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now, set the `Toolbar` as your action bar by first retrieving it and then using the `setSupportActionBar()`.

Since the gravity of the `TextView` is set to `center`, the text must be centered.

Comment: In my case, i set tool bar as actionbar. And i have an navigation icon in the left. By this way the title of toolbar doesn't center anymore. It's skewed to the right little bit. How to fix it?

Comment: You should use layout_gravity instead of gravity. gravity defines how the content inside view is placed inside it, where as layout_gravity tells how the view should be placed with respect to its parent.

Comment: @LạngHoàng you ever figure out your issue. I am running into same thing, nothing seems to solve it.

Comment: @Eggman87 try setting the WIDTH of your textview to WRAP_CONTENT and set its LAYOUT_GRAVITY to CENTER. That way, the textview will center itself inside the parent even with the home button displayed.

Comment: Doesn't work. Probably because I'm including a menu for the toolbar and this causes the layout for the TextView to get discarded.

Comment: You should also set the `gravity` and `layout_gravity` for the `Toolbar`.

Comment: it can't work on a `Activity` like `Scrolling Activity` however when you scroll down the custom `textview` will hide and original title will shown

Answer (score 11):

You can force the toolbar to the center by wrapping title and level right padding which has default left padding for title. Then put background color to the parent of toolbar and that way part which is cut out by wrapping title is in the same color(white in my example):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="56dp"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:paddingEnd="15dp"
               android:paddingRight="15dp"
               android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
               app:titleTextColor="@color/black"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is, that the back arrow button gets centered as wel..

Answer (score 10):

ToolBar is a View Group. so To 
Center Align The text Use

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/in.chabu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" 
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_sign_up

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.chabu.activities.SignUpActivity" >

    <include 
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Avtivity

```
public class SignUpActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just putting another `TextView` inside `Toolbar` is not enough to get title centered relative to the screen, its position will be dependent on other items in a toolbar (back button, menu items).

To make title centred you can manually set its position:

Extend `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` class and make following changes:

1. add `TextView`
2. override `onLayout()` and set `TextView` location to centre it (`titleView.setX((getWidth() - titleView.getWidth())/2)`)
3. override `setTitle()` where set title text to new text view

```
    public class CenteredToolbar extends Toolbar {

        private TextView titleView;

        public CenteredToolbar(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public CenteredToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.toolbarStyle);
        }

        public CenteredToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

            titleView = new TextView(getContext());

            int textAppearanceStyleResId;
            TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    new int[] { android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.titleTextAppearance }, defStyleAttr, 0);
            try {
                textAppearanceStyleResId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }
            if (textAppearanceStyleResId > 0) {
                titleView.setTextAppearance(context, textAppearanceStyleResId);
            }

            addView(titleView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            titleView.setX((getWidth() - titleView.getWidth())/2);
        }

        @Override
        public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
            titleView.setText(title);
        }
    }
```

In layout you can use this class like this:

```
<com.example.CenteredToolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>
```

Also, to make new title text look like standard title you should apply `titleTextAppearance` style to new `TextView` (`titleView.setTextAppearance(context, textAppearanceStyleResId)`).

Comment: this kind of tweak seems better. Is it possible to add another TextView on exact place of default title TextView in toolbar with overriding some functions? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315935/how-to-add-textview-in-same-location-of-title-in-toolbar)

Comment: @Mehmed do you need two TextViews in a toolbar (one centered and one on default position) or just one custom TextView on default position?
If the second option, you just need to remove overridden `onLayout` method and customize `titleView` TextView whatever you want in a constructor.

Comment: I need two textviews. I don't want to remove default title textview in toolbar to be able to use `toolbar.setTitle()` in the code. I want to add another textview on top of it. My aim is to animate between titles when I open drawer. My drawer is required to be under toolbar, that's why I am trying to do this. Thank you for the reply btw.

Comment: With code in the answer, original TextView is still there but it's empty because we overrode `setTitle()` method without calling `super.setTitle()`.

Comment: If you add `super.setTitle(title)` line, you will see two identical TextViews one by one.
And you can set location to new `titleView` in `onLayout()`.
`protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    TextView originalTitle = findOriginalTitleView();
    if (originalTitle != null) {
        titleView.setX(originalTitle.getX());
        titleView.setY(originalTitle.getY());
    }
}`
Where `findOriginalTitleView()` method just iterates through all children and tries to find original textView

Comment: It seems the best way for me to not to show default title and add an two textviews in a relative layout wrapped in the toolbar. Thanks.

Comment: This comment enlightens me for resolving the issue in my project. I will post my code as an answer.

Comment: It is the best solution.

Answer (score 9):

The final UI looks like:
[image]
For my project, I have navigation icon at left and menus (more than 1) at right, and want to put the Title at center.

I have `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, and `_actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_filter);`. 
My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/lib_action_bar_filter_view_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/lib_action_bar_filter_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My toolbar extends android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, then (kind of hard code) measure the size of the RelativeLayout, finally layout it at horizental center.

```
/**
 * Customized the <code>RelativeLayout</code> inside the <code>Toolbar</code>.
 * Because by default the custom view in the <code>Toolbar</code> cannot set
 * width as our expect value. So this class allows setting the width of the
 * <code>RelativeLayout</code> to take up any percentage of the screen width.
 */
public class CenteredToolbar extends Toolbar {

private static final double WIDTH_PERCENTAGE = 0.8;

private TextView titleView;

public CenteredToolbar(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CenteredToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.toolbarStyle);
}

public CenteredToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = this.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof RelativeLayout) {
            int width = getMeasuredWidth();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = (int) (width * WIDTH_PERCENTAGE);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = this.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof RelativeLayout) {
            forceTitleCenter(view);
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Centering the layout.
 *
 * @param view The view to be centered
 */
private void forceTitleCenter(View view) {
    int toolbarWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int relativeLayoutWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
    int newLeft = (int) (toolbarWidth - relativeLayoutWidth) / 2;
    int top = view.getTop();
    int newRight = newLeft + relativeLayoutWidth;
    int bottom = view.getBottom();
    view.layout(newLeft, top, newRight, bottom);
}
}
```

Attach my toolbar layout. Maybe you don't need this, I am just pasting out here for someone's reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.chinalwb.CenteredToolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/vmosolib_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 8):

When you have Home or Up button together with centered title, and the title isn't centered anymore and is moved slightly to the right a bit, set your textview as width=wrap_content and layout_gravity=center

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: wrap_content made it for me, I did try layout_gravity only before. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `MaterialToolbar`, it supported on android `material:1.4.0-alpha02`

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/cbf528e3a6deaa2bc39d0836b3a850b27c2ada49.

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'
```

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleCentered="true" />
```

Comment: This is really helpful in order to rid of custom implementations.

Answer (score 4):

I slightly modified the `Toolbar` source to make the title centre aligned.

```
public class CenterTitleToolbar extends Toolbar {
    private AppCompatTextView titleTextView;


    public CenterTitleToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenterTitleToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CenterTitleToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
            if (titleTextView == null) {
                final Context context = getContext();
                titleTextView = new AppCompatTextView(context);
                titleTextView.setSingleLine();
                titleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                titleTextView.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.TextAppearance_MaterialComponents_Headline6);
                final LayoutParams lp = generateDefaultLayoutParams();
                lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                titleTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
            if (titleTextView.getParent() != this) {
                addSystemView(titleTextView);
            }
        } else if (titleTextView != null && titleTextView.getParent() == this) {
            removeView(titleTextView);
        }
        if (titleTextView != null) {
            titleTextView.setText(title);
        }
    }

    private void addSystemView(View v) {
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams vlp = v.getLayoutParams();
        final LayoutParams lp;
        if (vlp == null) {
            lp = generateDefaultLayoutParams();
        } else if (!checkLayoutParams(vlp)) {
            lp = generateLayoutParams(vlp);
        } else {
            lp = (LayoutParams) vlp;
        }
        addView(v, lp);
    }

}
```

Text Style `TextAppearance_MaterialComponents_Headline6` is included in the new [Android Material library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Comment: What does `generateDefaultLayoutParams` returns?

Comment: @Vincent_Paing 
`protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() { return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); }`

`generateDefaultLayoutParams` method is declared in superclass.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @LiuWenbin_NO,

I had created a custom toolbar, which didn't need any extra view to center title in textview,

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.Gravity

class CenteredToolbar(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int):
Toolbar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null, 0)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : this(context, attrs, androidx.appcompat.R.attr.toolbarStyle)

override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)

    val childCount = childCount
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val view = this.getChildAt(i)
        if (view is TextView) {
            forceTitleCenter(view,l, r)
            break
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Centering the layout.
 *
 * @param view The view to be centered
 */
private fun forceTitleCenter(view: TextView, l: Int,  r: Int) {
    val top = view.getTop()
    val bottom = view.getBottom()
    view.layout(l, top, r, bottom)
    navigationIcon?.let{
        view.setPadding(it.intrinsicWidth,0,0,0)
    }
    view.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
}
```

}

```
 <ui.customView.CenteredToolbar
                android:id="@+id/apd_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
                app:title="Check Title"
                app:elevation="4dp"/>
```

Comment: The back icon doesn't center vertically

Answer (score 2):

As far as toolbar is a view group so you can create layouts inside it .
Follow these steps

1-Create a textview inside your Toolbar
2-make your textview gravity center

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/secondary_text"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand you Question Completely .. but i found Solution Like this

To use a custom title in your Toolbar all you need to do is remember is that Toolbar is just a fancy ViewGroup so you can add a custom title like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This means that you can style the TextView however you would like because it's just a regular TextView. So in your activity you can access the title like so:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Comment: But this implement show me both default title and title that is mentioned into the tool bar.

Comment: hey check this link hope this would be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554996/change-toolbar-color-in-appcompat-21

Answer (score 1):

```
public void centerTitleAndSubtitle(Toolbar toolbar){
    // Save current title and subtitle
    final CharSequence originalTitle = toolbar.getTitle();
    final CharSequence originalSubtitle = toolbar.getSubtitle();

    // Temporarily modify title and subtitle to help detecting each
    toolbar.setTitle("title");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("subtitle");

    for(int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
        View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);

        if(view instanceof TextView){
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;


            if(textView.getText().equals("title")){
                // Customize title's TextView
                Toolbar.LayoutParams params = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                textView.setLayoutParams(params);

            } else if(textView.getText().equals("subtitle")){
                // Customize subtitle's TextView
                Toolbar.LayoutParams params = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                textView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }

        // Restore title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle(originalTitle);
        toolbar.setSubtitle(originalSubtitle);
    }
}
```

If you also want a custom font, check out my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35723158/445548

Answer (score 1):

Use custom title (with gravity center) inside toolbar

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar           
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
         android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
         android:elevation="4dp"
         android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
         app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
         app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
         app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" >

      <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: That thing I know. Your previous answer was using styles so I had gone for it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution will be to use a nested `TextView` in the `ToolBar` then set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content`. Then set the `layout_gravity` to `center`. This way it is not offset by other icons in the `toolbar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MaterialToolbar and set app:titleCentered="true" in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

This did my work!

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
        TextView titleText = getProperties(new TextView(this));
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        frameLayout.addView(titleText);
        toolbar.addView(frameLayout);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Method to Set TextView Properties

```
 private TextView getProperties(TextView titleText){
        titleText.setText(wallpaperName);
        titleText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        titleText.setTextSize(18f);
        titleText.setShadowLayer(2f,2f,2f,Color.BLACK);
        titleText.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER); // CENTER ALIGNMENT
        return titleText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In koltin Just one function can help you out...**

```
    private fun centerTitle(toolbar: Toolbar) {
    // Save current title
    val originalTitle: CharSequence = toolbar.title
    // Temporarily modify title
    toolbar.title = "title"
    for (i in 0 until toolbar.childCount) {
        val view: View = toolbar.getChildAt(i)
        if (view is TextView) {
            if (view.text == "title") {
                // Customize title's TextView
                val params: Toolbar.LayoutParams = Toolbar.LayoutParams(
                    Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
                view.layoutParams = params
            }
        }
        // Restore title
        toolbar.title = originalTitle
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for kotlin users
from @user2137020 answer:

```
package com.example.safetyofficer.view

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.example.safetyofficer.R


class CustomToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.toolbarStyle
) :
    Toolbar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private val titleView: TextView = TextView(getContext())

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)
        titleView.x = (width - titleView.width) / 2.toFloat()
    }

    override fun setTitle(title: CharSequence) {
        titleView.text = title
    }

    init {
        val textAppearanceStyleResId: Int
        val a = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            intArrayOf(R.attr.titleTextAppearance),
            defStyleAttr,
            0
        )
        textAppearanceStyleResId = try {
            a.getResourceId(0, 0)
        } finally {
            a.recycle()
        }
        if (textAppearanceStyleResId > 0) {
            titleView.setTextAppearance(textAppearanceStyleResId)
        }
        addView(titleView, LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

you can insert this code to your code

```
SupportActionBar.Title = "title";
```

Comment: SupportActionBar doesn´t exists!