# How to add TextView in same location of title in Toolbar?

Tags: android, textview, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar in my xml file, with no child views defined in it. I want to add a TextView on exact location of default title in toolbar when we call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`. On particular events, I like to fade in or out these two views in case of particular events.

I tried to do the following in `onCreate()` of the activity, but nothing is visible except the default title in toolbar.

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(toolbarTitle.getLayoutParams());
    tv.setHeight(toolbarTitle.getHeight());
    tv.setWidth(toolbarTitle.getWidth());
    tv.setText("Other Title");
    tv.setLeft(toolbarTitle.getLeft());
    toolbar.addView(tv);
```

I also tried to add a RelativeLayout inside the toolbar with width and height set to match parent, but this time, default title TextView of toolbar disappears.

How can add another TextView on exact location of default title TextView in toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disable title in toolbar using `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` in `onCreate()` method of my activity and put two overlapping textViews encapsulating them with relativeLayout inside toolbar in layout. Then I animate them as I want. While changing text, I used `titleTextView.setText()` rather then `toolbar.setTitle()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AppBarLayout` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/aadhaar_sign_up"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18.0sp"
    app:fontName="Font-Medium.ttf"
    />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then you use the textview as below

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title)).setText(title);
```

Comment: this will give one textview, right? I want original textview to stay where it is plus to add one

Comment: I want the original title TextView to stay but when I add another TextView it disappears. My question is how can I keep the original TextView and put another TextView on it :/