# Center title in AppBarLayout with MaterialToolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I try to center the text in my toolbar. I use `AppBarLayout` and `MaterialToolbar`, as suggested in [Material Design](https://material.io/develop/android/components/top-app-bars/).

I tried everything I found on StackOverflow to center the title, but nothing seemed to work.

This is my toolbar:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        style="@style/CenteredToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And `CenteredToolbar` is my custom style where I tried to center the title:

```
<style name="CenteredToolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

This doesn't work, however.

Any suggestions on what I can do to center the title?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to Center title in ToolBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443604/android-how-to-center-title-in-toolbar)

Comment: No it does not. Placing a TextView into the MaterialToolbar removes the text style, and I lose functionality like setting the title according to the selected tab on a bottom navigation (with `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)`.

Comment: Try using foregroundGravity instead of gravity in your style or directly in your xml layout file.

Comment: That doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 2):

I shared my answer for this here. From `com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0` there's `app:titleCentered="true"`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589951/2810726

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have find only this method to create a centered title in the toolbar.

**Bonus:** you will have a complete control of toolbar's UI.

Create a custom layout for using it as toolbar like this.

**activity_action_bar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_preference"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextMain" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your **interface** layout XML include toolbar like this.

```
<include layout="@layout/activity_action_bar" />
```

Now in the class where you setContentView with the previous interface layout do this.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_interface);
    // create and define a custom action bar
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_action_bar, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView Title = view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
    Title.setText(getString(R.string.about));
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view,params);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // show custom title
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // hide the default title
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))); // set background
```

This will give you a full management of the toolbar, such as centered title or custom UI.

Result:[image: result]

Comment: I am still having the same problems with centering the text in a material toolbar. Material Toolbar does stupid things when you only display one of the edge accessories (up nav/overflow menu). Can't believe Google have still not addressed this.

Comment: @angryITguy Their move were simple: they deprecated and not suggesting anymore the usage of nav menu.

Comment: @angryITguy this is already provided https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589962/2810726

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have solved the problem. Works fine for me. I used material design theme.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
            android:text="Manali" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice See the demo.

Comment: It's not actually centered. The issue is also when you display up-nav on the left and hide overflow menu. Developers need to centre the text independently of these extra bits

Comment: @angryITguy, you should give different solution because I didn't find any other. Just using this solution in all of my projects.

Comment: i would, but i dont have time to invest in that right now. But it's important for SO users to know that it did not centre. (I was using Android 8.1 at the time. Subsequent version may differ.)