# MaterialToolbar titleCentered attribute not available

Tags: android, xml

I want to center the text title on the Toolbar by using app:titleCentered. But not available

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/idToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarFontStyle" />
```

All libraries are updated, so what to do?

Comment: im assuming you checked these answers and they didn work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664298/change-the-title-of-materialtoolbar-into-center/69589951#69589951

Comment: @Fiehra Yes, as already mentioned. I've updated all the libraries to the new ones. Any other solutions?

Comment: i saw people using app.title="title" together with app.titleCentered