# How to change the toolbar and tablayout color dynamically?

Tags: android, toolbar, fragmentpageradapter, android-tablayout

How to dynamically change the tablayout and toolbar color, while navigating through other fragment pager?

[image: Screenshot of Android]

I want to add different color to my all fragmentpageradapter.

Comment: You've added a deprecated tag, so I have swapped it to `fragmentpageradapter`. Please adjust if this is incorrect. Please also add your code and any research relating to this problem - the question is a little brief at present!

Comment: actually my reputation is very less so i am not able to add images of the specified problem i am facing

Comment: Upload any images to `imgur.com` and add the link instead. But please also add code as well.

Comment: okay wait :) btw thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Great. Now, what have you found from researching here and in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Latest SDK APIs let's you treat the support Toolbar (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`) like any other vie in your app. So I would expect something like this inside your `onStart()` call:

```
    actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
    super.onStart();
```

Once you succesfully obtained this reference, you can change the Bar's color dynamically acting on its background, like how you would with another kind of view. Have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554996/change-toolbar-color-in-appcompat-21) answer for an example; you may also find [this tutorial](https://snow.dog/blog/how-to-dynamicaly-change-android-toolbar-icons-color/) useful

Comment: dear shine i know how to set toolbar color but how to set different color when i move too one pager to another like suppose i am in open view pager dat viewpager color toolbar color and tab layout color is red then when i come too another viewpager i want toolbar color blue and also tablayout color blue

Comment: the view pager should expose methods to let you know when a "screenswipe" has been completed...finishUpdate() is an example, if you're using FragmentPagerAdapter..