# How to change background for Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles

I have a big problem. I cant set background for `ToolBar` when I start `ActionMode`.

I got this:

[image]

I try much variants, but I didn't find answer for me (
This is my style:

```
<style name="DriverNotesAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_bg</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/edittext_primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/material_light_bg</item>

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/WhiteDrawerIconStyle</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>

    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/LStyled.ActionMode</item>


    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>

    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/myPopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="LStyled.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/material_light_bg</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Chek [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460452/title-bar-background-color-change-in-anroid-studio-in-api-leve-11/34460500#34460500). I hope it will help to solve.

Comment: update tag android-layout tag as well

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
```

**Theme / Style**

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle">
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/Theme.Toolbar.Title</item>
    <!-- No need for colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent here
         this should go to the AppTheme -->
</style>
```

for more detail visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561223/2826147)