# Title bar background color change in android studio in API Leve 11+

Tags: android, android-studio

I have try to change style.xml to change app theme like following:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme" >
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_color</item>
</style>
```

give me nice solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refers these link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color

Comment: there is no solution found as per my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this; I hope this is what you want and will help you:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#009000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Then upvote please @SubhashKhimani =)