# CollapsingToolbar with different toolbar color

Tags: android, android-studio, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am creating an activity with collapsing toolbar layout.
My toolbar has different color and with a parralax image.
What i want is to get I have different color of toolbar and when collpased,
the toolbar color will be change to another color.

Here's my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.toweelo.activity.ViewReviews">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="310dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/toweelo_2"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="18dp"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_view_reviews"/>
```

ATM, i only getting this result.
The white is my toolbar. And it should be white at start,
and then after collapsing it would be chnage to other color.
[image]

I want the image to be under the toolbar.

Here is the sample of what am i doing..
In the first image, its not yet collpased.
And when the user scroll, the result will be the image 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This is what you need, check the implementation and replace your things in it:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/activityusrlayout" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/header"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imghd"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tbbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_acc"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_acc"
        app:backgroundTint="#DD2C00"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Here is the important code inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:**

```
 app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

Comment: as you can see in the picture, the image is overlapping in toolbar

Comment: I added the pic with the result of your given XML.. I am getting the same result.. and the title should be fixed its should be always inside the toolbar.

Comment: I Also added sample image of what am i doing. thanks for your help

Comment: @CharlesGalvez - let me know if that worked for you.btw, i'm using it in my app.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply. No internet since then, btw. i tried your code and it seems to work, but having a problem with the toolbar. I need it to be colored white, and when collapse it changed back to primary color

Comment: Hello, check the contentscrim and that is ok so far.for set white color to toolbar, that is another question and already has answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26555178/4409113 - goodluck!

Comment: Above comment was about the texts, and for white background, use: `android:background="@color/colorWhite"` that's all.

Comment: That worked. THe toolbar changes to white, but when it collapsed its still white. :'(

Comment: Check this example:https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/app_container_view.xml it's working