# Action bar background color XML

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've reading lot of stuff about styling the Action Bar and changing the Action Bar background color using XML, posts like [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

But the point is that my Action Bar does not change from its default dark grey color. To summarize and keep it simple, I've got this in my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">...</item>
</style>
```

I think the problem may come from my parent Theme (Base.Theme [...]). But I cannot change it, I need the AppCompat component.

By the way, I've changed the color succesfully programatically using:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(...));
```

But doing so I have this code repeated in every activity...something I want to avoid using the styles xml.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Finally got it, just need to add

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item> 
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark</item>
```

Besides the android:[...], the attr needed were the previous

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554996/change-toolbar-color-in-appcompat-21

Comment: @g2o nop, I'm sure in the end it will be nothing...but for the moment I can't find where the error is...Thanks!

Comment: please post your layout and your activity