# Need to change Tittle bar color in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, appcompatactivity, android-appcompat

Hello I make one `AppCompatActivity` as a `BaseActivity` and in other all activity I extends with `BaseActivity`.
Now in other classes I have to change `tittle bar color` and `Tittle text`.

This is my toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="@string/app_name" />
```

And setActionbar

```
@Override
public void setactionbar(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 

}
```

But not get success to change color and text

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you tried by setting a different theme to that class?

Comment: did you try changing the `colorPrimary` in `colors.xml` ??

Comment: try changing the color.xml . and if the problem still happens post your style.xml here.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554996/change-toolbar-color-in-appcompat-21

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#95CDBA")));
    actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000099'>Title bar</font>"));
```

or

```
  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor)));
```

and also add this if want enable title or disable

```
  actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); //for enable or false for disable
```

For toolbar you need to like that

```
 toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

or

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor);
```

For background

```
 toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way to do it is,
First,
Change you theme to...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/your_title_bar_color</item> // default toolbar or actionbar color
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/your_title_bar_color_dark</item> //statusbar color
</style>
```

Now change your toolbar to,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/your_title_bar_color"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

Now, in the class- make the method

```
private void setupToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}
```

All you need to do is call `setupToolbar()`.
Happy coding.